# How to import ipcRenderer in vue.js ? __dirname is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, electron, ipcrenderer

I'm struggling to understand how to correctly import ipcRenderer in a .vue file.

I put in /src/background.js file :

```
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration:false,
  contextIsolation: true, // protects against prototype pollution
  preload: path.join(__dirname, "../dist_electron/preload.js"),
}
```

And, based on https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration I put in preload.js :

```
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer
```

webpack.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/background.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'background.js'
  }
}
```

In order to facilitate the debugging, I created a github repo.
You can git clone the repo from here: https://github.com/raphael10-collab/ElectronVueTypeScriptScaffolding.git

After executing yarn -> yarn electron:serve
you will get the correct page.

But when activating in /src/views/Home.vue this line:

//import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

you will get this error:

[__dirname is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Z4HP.png)

```
Environment Info:

  System:
    OS: Linux 5.4 Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4790K CPU @ 4.00GHz
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.5.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.4 - /usr/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.5 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.5.0/bin/npm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 85.0.4183.83
    Firefox: 79.0
  npmPackages:
    @vue/babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props:  1.0.0 
    @vue/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-preset-app:  4.4.6 
    @vue/babel-preset-jsx:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-functional-vue:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-inject-h:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-v-model:  1.1.2 
    @vue/babel-sugar-v-on:  1.1.2 
    @vue/cli-overlay:  4.4.6 
    @vue/cli-plugin-babel: ~4.4.0 => 4.4.6 
    @vue/cli-plugin-e2e-cypress: ~4.4.0 => 4.4.6 
    @vue/cli-plugin-router: ~4.4.0 => 4.4.6 
    @vue/cli-plugin-typescript: ~4.4.0 => 4.4.6 
    @vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha: ~4.4.0 => 4.4.6 
    @vue/cli-plugin-vuex: ~4.4.0 => 4.4.6 
    @vue/cli-service: ~4.4.0 => 4.4.6 
    @vue/cli-shared-utils:  4.4.6 
    @vue/component-compiler-utils:  3.2.0 
    @vue/preload-webpack-plugin:  1.1.2 
    @vue/test-utils: ^1.0.3 => 1.0.3 
    @vue/web-component-wrapper:  1.2.0 
    babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props:  2.0.3 
    typescript: ^3.9.7 => 3.9.7 
    vue: ^2.6.11 => 2.6.11 
    vue-class-component: ^7.2.5 => 7.2.5 
    vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder: ~2.0.0-rc.4 => 2.0.0-rc.4 
    vue-hot-reload-api:  2.3.4 
    vue-i18n: ^8.20.0 => 8.20.0 
    vue-loader:  15.9.3 
    vue-property-decorator: ^9.0.0 => 9.0.0 
    vue-router: ^3.2.0 => 3.3.4 
    vue-style-loader:  4.1.2 
    vue-template-compiler: ^2.6.11 => 2.6.11 
    vue-template-es2015-compiler:  1.9.1 
    vuex: ^3.5.1 => 3.5.1 
    vuex-class: ^0.3.2 => 0.3.2 
  npmGlobalPackages:
    @vue/cli: 4.4.6

node version: v14.5.0
```

Update 1)

I tried to set webPreferences as follows (with nodeIntegration: true) :

```
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration: true,
  //contextIsolation: true, // protects against prototype pollution
  //preload: path.join(__dirname, "../dist_electron/preload.js"),
},
```

and got this error:

[fs.existsSync is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxuEz.png)

Searching around for info about this kind of problem, I found this post:
[How to resolve fs.existsSync is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53841364/how-to-resolve-fs-existssync-is-not-a-function)
With this link: https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/

But I already specified in webpack.config.js the target ‘node’:

in webpack.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/background.js',
  target: 'node',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'background.js'
  }
}
```

So... how to solve this new problem?

By the way,
Why must I put

```
webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true,
}
```

if, for security reasons, it is more secure to have:

```
webPreferences: {
  nodeIntegration:false,
  contextIsolation: true, // protects against prototype pollution
  preload: path.join(__dirname, "../dist_electron/preload.js"),
}
```

dist_electron/preload.js :

```
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {
        send: (channel, data) => {
            // whitelist channels
            let validChannels = ["toMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, data);
            }
        },
        receive: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["fromMain"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender` 
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) =>   
func(...args));
            }
        }
    }
);

window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer
```

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/security#electron-security-warnings

Update 2)

in vue.config.js I've put:

```
module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      preload: 'dist_electron/preload.js',
      // Or, for multiple preload files:
      //preload: { preload: 'src/preload.js', otherPreload: 
      //'src/preload2.js' }
    }
  }
}
```

But I get the same error when I do

```
yarn electron:serve
```

[UncaughtReferenceError: __dirname is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wYOG.png)

When setting nodeIntegration: true (but I would prefer to set it to false, and use preload.js file), I get this other error (as above):

```
Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function
```

[Uncaught TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZQQZ.png)

How to solve the problem?
Looking forward to your kind help

Answer (score 26):

## Updated Answer - Nodeintegration disabled and contextIsolation enabled

In order to use the ipcRenderer with Vue CLI plugin Electron Builder you need to first setup electron to utilize a preload.js file.

Inside your `vue.config.js` file you need to add the `preload.js` path like this:

```
// vue.config.js - project root

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      preload: 'src/preload.js',
      // Or, for multiple preload files:
      preload: { preload: 'src/preload.js', otherPreload: 'src/preload2.js' }
    }
  }
}
```

Next you need to updated your `background.js` file to use `preload.js` in the web preferences like this:

```
// src/background.js

const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
    // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
    nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
    contextIsolation: !process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
    enableRemoteModule: true,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
  },
})
```

> Note: `nodeIntegration` is disabled and `contextIsolation` is enabled by default

Once you have that complete you can create the `preload.js` file in your src directory.
With `contextIsolation` enabled you need to import the `contextBridge` along with `ipcRenderer`. Then you can can expose the `ipcRenderer` to your client.

Then add this to the file:

```
// src/preload.js

import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

// Expose ipcRenderer to the client
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', {
  send: (channel, data) => {
    let validChannels = ['nameOfClientChannel'] // <-- Array of all ipcRenderer Channels used in the client
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, data)
    }
  },
  receive: (channel, func) => {
    let validChannels = ['nameOfElectronChannel'] // <-- Array of all ipcMain Channels used in the electron
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args))
    }
  }
})
```

> Note: You need to make sure your `preload.js` file is in the `src` folder and not `dist_electron`

To test and make sure the preload file is working you can also create an alert in the `preload.js` file

```
// src/preload.js

import { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } from 'electron'

// Expose ipcRenderer to the client
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('ipcRenderer', {
  send: (channel, data) => {
    let validChannels = ['nameOfClientChannel'] // <-- Array of all ipcRenderer Channels used in the client
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      ipcRenderer.send(channel, data)
    }
  },
  receive: (channel, func) => {
    let validChannels = ['nameOfElectronChannel'] // <-- Array of all ipcMain Channels used in the electron
    if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
      // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`
      ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => func(...args))
    }
  }
})

alert("It Worked!") // Remove this line once you confirm it worked
```

When you have verified that your preload script is working correctly, you can access the `ipcRenderer` from your vue app.

like this:

```
// src/App.vue

<template>
     \\ Some html
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "App",
    methods: {
      test(){
        window.ipcRenderer.send(channel, args...) // or any other ipcRenderer method you want to invoke
    }
};
</script>
```

In electron you can listen for those events

```
// background.js
ipcMain.on(channel, (event, args) => {
  // Do stuff
});
```

> Sources:
>
> - [Preload Files](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/guide.html#preload-files)
> - [Node Integration](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration)
> - [With contextIsolation = true, is it possible to use ipcRenderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55164360/with-contextisolation-true-is-it-possible-to-use-ipcrenderer/59675116#59675116)

## Original Answer

In order to use the ipcRenderer with Vue CLI plugin Electron Builder you need to first setup electron to utilize a preload.js file.

Inside your `vue.config.js` file you need to add the `preload.js` path like this:

```
// vue.config.js - project root

module.exports = {
  pluginOptions: {
    electronBuilder: {
      preload: 'src/preload.js',
      // Or, for multiple preload files:
      preload: { preload: 'src/preload.js', otherPreload: 'src/preload2.js' }
    }
  }
}
```

Next you need to updated your `background.js` file to use `preload.js` in the web preferences like this:

```
// src/background.js

const win = new BrowserWindow({
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  webPreferences: {
    // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
    // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/configuration.html#node-integration for more info
    nodeIntegration: process.env.ELECTRON_NODE_INTEGRATION,
+   preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
  }
})
```

Once you have that complete you can create the `preload.js` file in your src directory

Then add this to the file:

```
// src/preload.js

import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer
```

> Note: You need to make sure your `preload.js` file is in the `src` folder and not `dist_electron`

To test and make sure the preload file is working you can also create an alert in the `preload.js` file

```
// src/preload.js

import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer

alert("It Worked!") // Remove this line once you confirm it worked
```

When you have verified that your preload script is working correctly, you can access the ipcRenderer from your vue app.

like this:

```
// src/App.vue

<template>
     \\ Some html
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "App",
    methods: {
      test(){
        window.ipcRenderer.send(channel, args...) // or any other ipcRenderer method you want to invoke
    }
};
</script>
```

> Sources:
>
> - [Preload Files](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/guide.html#preload-files)
> - [Node Integration](https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration)

Comment: Worked for me but this is some crazy boilerplate...

Comment: This solution comes from the Vue CLI Plugin Electron Builder documentation.  
https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/guide.html#preload-files

It took a while to read through it, but it was pretty straight forward after reading it a few times.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that doc is helpful, I wish they would show an example of using the shared windowed object like you did, thats a bit of a gap in that section IMO.

Comment: not work `console.log( window.ipcRenderer)` = undefinded :|

Comment: @A1Gard Can you ask a new question with the issue you are experiencing and link it here. I will do my best to assist.

Comment: @Lateralus, this works great for on and send, but what about invoke? I can't figure out how to add it properly to preload.js in a way that allows the render process to receive a valid ressponse.

Comment: YOU SAVED MY LIFE, I SEND YOU BIG LOVE WAVES ! <3

(unstuck my Electron problem with Nuxt 3)

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was setting the electron window's `contextIsolation` to `false`.

So in your `main.js` wherever you create a `BrowserWindow` it would look like this:

```
const win = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    contextIsolation: false,
    preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
  },
})
```

And then in `preload.js` you can simply do

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')
window.ipcRenderer = ipcRenderer
```

And then you'll have access to `ipcRenderer` anywhere in your vue code.

It seems that in the current version of electron `contextIsolation` defaults to `true`, which makes the `window` that `preload.js` sees different from the one your vue app sees.

Comment: Don't do this, you are turning of security measures and using a non-recommended approach of deliberating the IPC use for the Renderer process, while it should to be able to use just same previously defined IPC names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `nodeIntegration` to `true`.

This enables NodeJs in the renderer process (i.e the front-end) so you can use stuff like fs (FileSystem) and other NodeJs-only features in your Vue code.

As ipcRenderer requires NodeJs's environnement too (__dirname is a global variable for NodeJs only), it needs to be activated.

Comment: Hi @Oussama!! Thank you for helping!! I updated my post with Update 1)

Comment: Hi, yes you're correct for the preload.js solution, it's more secure but the downside is you're going to put logic inside public/ folder which is not very ideal. 

As for the error, since you're using `vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder`, i suggest you try adding your configuration inside a `vue.config.js` as stated here in the docs : https://nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/guide.html#preload-files

And, just to be sure, make sure you are running your app using `yarn electron:serve` and not in the browser.

Comment: I've been using yarn electron:serve when trying to run my app. I updated my post with update 2). Thank you for helping.